Как организовать работу с базой данных на удаленной виртуальной машине?
Короче, я не разбираюсь в бэкенде. Просто делаю на андройд студио. Мне надо чтобы при регистрации по кнопке "Зарегистрироваться", с помощью библиотеки, отправлялся запрос на эту виртульную машину, там будет база данных, которая и будет обрабатывать запрос и добавлять в бд. Как это вообще можно реализовать? Как настроить под это виртуальную машину?

На машине поднимаете сервис(сервер обработчик), который как раз будет принимать сообщения от клиента, обрабатывать их, записывать в БД, отдавать ответы. Напрямую с клиента в БД вы данные не передадите(в большинстве случаев, если только сама БД не умеет поднимать для себя сервис по приему сообщений). Ну а на чем писать серверную часть, решайте сами, тут нет ограничений

какие есть способы поднять сервис(самый простой)?

Нанять бэкэнд разработчика - это самое простое. Там же не все так просто. Надо определиться с языком программирования, БД, прописать весь код: получить запрос, проверить, обработать, отправить данные в БД, получить подтверждение от БД, вернуть ответ. Залогировать действие и куча всего прочего
